# php/mysql ignore input if null

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there anyway to ignore the inputs if they are null and still succeed to update the values that are entered? For example if I only give **itemID1** an value and **itemID2** is `null`.

```
$upd = "UPDATE booking SET status='$status', CalDate='$CalDate', DueDate='$DueDate' WHERE itemID IN ('$itemID1', '$itemID2')";
```

Comment: @Sadikhasan: thanks for all your editing! In this case, since the columns you have emboldened are essentially code, backticks would be better - bold is essentially for spoken emphasis in ordinary writing. I wouldn't normally mention this, but you've made a lot of this kind of edit, and people may end up changing them later on. (Some of your edits are probably also too minor: "I'm" is an acceptable contraction, and it does not need expanding to "I am").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `isset` function in php

```
if(isset($itemID1) && isset($itemID2)){
$upd = "UPDATE booking SET status='$status', CalDate='$CalDate', DueDate='$DueDate' WHERE itemID IN ('$itemID1', '$itemID2')";
}
```

Or check it using `empty` function

```
if(!empty($itemID1) && !empty($itemID2)){
$upd = "UPDATE booking SET status='$status', CalDate='$CalDate', DueDate='$DueDate' WHERE itemID IN ('$itemID1', '$itemID2')";
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not using PDO or active records, So in your case following might help.

```
<?php

$items = array(
    'itemID1' => "Hello",
    'itemID2' => "",
    'itemID3' => "World"
    );

$item = "'".implode("', '", array_filter($items))."'";
$upd = "UPDATE booking SET status='status', CalDate='CalDate', DueDate='DueDate' WHERE itemID IN ($item)";

echo $upd;
?>
```

hope this helps.

Also you have to make sure you change these status='status', CalDate='CalDate', DueDate='DueDate' (I removed the $ to make them string from variable), if you plan to copy paste the above piece of code.

Comment: Yeah I just use plain up php code, but my problem is fixed now. Thanks anyway :)